# Start and stop AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a requirement in which I need to automate the start and stop of the AWS EC2 Instances (within Autoscaling group) daily. This is mainly to prevent cost. I have built a Python script to start and stop EC2 instances but it's not working properly as EC2 instances are within an Autoscaling group.
Does anybody know any solution for this?

Comment: can you share a snippet of your code if possible, that will help people better answer your question

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group is designed to **automatically scale** so that extra instances can be added when there is a higher workload and instances can be removed when there is less workload.

Auto Scaling is also good for ensuring the health of an application. If an instance in an Auto Scaling group fails a health check, it will be automatically terminated. Auto Scaling will then launch a new instance to replace it.

It appears that your requirement is to reduce costs when the application is not being used. This can be done by creating a **scaling policy** that defines when Auto Scaling should add and remove instances, such as:

- Add an instance when the **average CPU Utilization** exceeds 65% (across all instances) over a 15-minute period
- Remove an instance when the average CPU Utilization is below 30% over a 30-minute period

(Note that it is normally good to scale-out quickly, but scale-in slowly.)

By using scaling policies like this, or even [automatic Target Tracking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html), Auto Scaling will take care of things for you.

If, on the other hand, you wish to **control the Auto Scaling group manually**, you can add and remove instances using:

- [`set_desired_capacity()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.set_desired_capacity) to tell Auto Scaling how many instances you want (and let it launch/terminate instances to match)
- [`terminate_instance_in_auto_scaling_group()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.terminate_instance_in_auto_scaling_group) to remove *specific* instances from the Auto Scaling group

You should **never directly stop/terminate instances in an Auto Scaling group** otherwise Auto Scaling will presume that the instance is failed and will automatically launch a replacement.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your amnswer.But our requirement is to start stop EC2 instances based on Schedule using the Lambfa Function.Please note all our EC2 instances are within Autoscaling group.We do have scheduler configured manually in the Autoscaling group but we will like to automate it using Lamba function/Cloudwatch.

Comment: _WHY_ are the instances in an Auto Scaling group? Your requirement seems to not be compatible with using an Auto Scaling group.

Comment: Hi John, The EC2 isntances are stopped and started from the Autoscaling group if we are doing it manually where we are increasing and decreasing the desired capacity.Also we have used the scheduled action features in the Autoscaling group.Is it possible to use Lamba function and Cloudwatch to somewhat automate it so that th Ec2 Instances stops are Business hours and starts next day before the business hours start.The timings will be an input.

Comment: Firstly, please note that Auto Scaling does not Stop and Start -- it Terminates and Launches (big difference!). How is [Scheduled Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html) not meeting your needs? Yes, you can control it via API calls from Lambda, via the above API calls. But, the reality is that you should have Scaling Policies that can auto-adjust for demand (which is the whole purpose of using an Auto Scaling group).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is automate the auto scaling parameters, for desired instances, min instances and max instances. Ideally, you want to change the desired instance amount. This will cause the auto scaler to terminate excessive instances, to meet the desired instance amount.

Comment: ideally you want answers to be more informative, perhaps share links or have code snippets, as it stands this is not what I would classify a good answer, also it would be beneficial to wait for OP to post some code before answering questions

Comment: Sorry I was just posting in a hurry, will start providing more informative answers, thank you